# Minimal linux that can run Qt GUI application

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I'm making a homebrew video-game console (simple low spec pc) that will constantly run one application (game) which will be created with Qt (it's a requirement, preferably with gpu acceleration). So OS should be lightweight to boot as fast as possible and run the game.

How can this be achieved? Are there any linux distros that already fit my needs? What's with the embedded linux? (I'm new with linux customization)

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you maybe want to run Qt for embedded Linux, i.e. so that the Qt app draws directly to the system's video hardware rather than going through a windowing system?  https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/embedded-linux.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.tinycorelinux.com/

a 10 MB Linux distribution. boots within a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! I can see more than one way of doing this. But to prototype, you can use something like Suse Studio - http://susestudio.com/ to create a minimal distro for you.

Another interesting direction would be to use e.g. a phone like Nokia [N900](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_N900) which is based on Linux and uses QT as one of the technology available to run GUIs. It may already have hardware acceleration and TV out.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [MeeGo](http://meego.com/) project.

Answer (score 0):

There are tools to create [distros](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/linux-live-usb-creator-virtualization-tool/) for you. Might make your life simpler. You'll have to find out the minimum requirements for Qt from them and add those to your distro as you build it.